# why is 2 printed as a prime when if statement says it should not be

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know 2 is a prime number, but when this code is ran it doesn't match the if statement condition `if n % x == 0`. but `2 % 2 == 0` so it should be a equal:

```
for n in range(2, 10):
    for x in range(2, n):
        if n % x == 0:
           print(n, 'equals', x, '*', n//x)
           break
    else:
    # loop fell through without finding a factor
         print(n, 'is a prime number')
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

Comment: @AndrewL.It's _ironic_ that you're posting a link to the [same place where the OP got the code](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) for his/her question :-) Which the OP should have mentioned.

Comment: What makes you think it ever tests `2 % 2`?

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase well at the time i thought that n was the  iteration from 2 to 9 in for x in range(2,n) and x = 2 and n = 2 would be excuted in the if statement condition

Answer (score 5):

From the Python documentation of [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range)

> For a positive *step*, the contents of a range `r` are determined by the formula `r[i] = start + step*i` where `i >= 0` and `r[i] < stop`.
>
> A range object will be empty if `r[0]` does not meet the value constraint.

So when `n = 2`, `range(2, n)` is an empty range, because `r[0]` is `2` and that doesn't meet the constraint `2 < 2`. Therefore `for` loop never runs, so it never breaks, and as a result, the `else:` block is executed and reports that it's prime.

Comment: The second parameter is called "stop" and the value used here is n. So I'd say it does stop at n. And since this is about Python 3, `range(2, n)` is not a list.